# Share Ubuntu Internet Connection With Raspberry Pi 0

Tags: raspbian-stretch, ubuntu, internet

I'm connecting to my raspberry pi zero over USB and SSH currently but would like to share my computer's internet connection to it over the same USB cord. I've seen people do it on Windows and Mac but haven't been able to find anything for Ubuntu users.